# Localization workflow for updating development language

Tags: swift, xcode, localization, xliff

I have a project where I've setup localization using `NSLocalizedString` with keys instead of actual values for text parameters, i.e. something like this:

`NSLocalizedString("RunningDistance", "distance for a marathon")`

instead of this:

`NSLocalizedString("Running distance.", "distance for a marathon")`

Then, I exported them to `xliff` for translation and imported back; and it's all working.
Now, I want to add new strings (and lots of them).

I read that it is currently not recommended (and supported) to use `genstrings` for swift. 
I thought I should export the development language to xliff, add translations and reimport. I tried this and I get the `The XLIFF file does not contain a target language` error.

1. Does this mean I need to add all those strings manually into `Localizable.strings` and elsewhere (as I'm using base localizations)?
2. Is there any other way to get this done, and import my base language `xliff`?